# App is crashing in Android 13 , Injecting input events Injecting input events requires the caller (to have the INJECT_EVENTS permission

Tags: android, android-13

I have implemented MultiSelectSpinner from https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner which is giving issue in android 13,please someone know how to resolve this issue ?
I have given INJECT_EVENTS permission in my manifest file , but still app is crashing and giving the same error

```
``
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting input events requires the caller (or the source of the instrumentation, if any) to have the INJECT_EVENTS permission.
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3040)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3024)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3007)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2949)
at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEventToTarget(IInputManager.java:1294)
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:1151)
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:1180)
at android.app.Instrumentation.sendKeySync(Instrumentation.java:1135)
at android.app.Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(Instrumentation.java:1147)
at com.androidbuts.multispinnerfilter.MultiSpinnerSearch.lambda$onCancel$0(MultiSpinnerSearch.java:185)
at com.androidbuts.multispinnerfilter.-$$Lambda$MultiSpinnerSearch$p9xhRiNPdc-qw9SrA8LUwZsjeq0.run()
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) `your text`
``
```